# Cucumber/Capybara: Test is not accurately reflecting real world use. It is ignoring page errors and passing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I did a total rearrangement of my routes so I'm having to go back and change some path names. I ran a cucumber test for my navigation and it came back a success. Knowing that I have some old routes to change I thought that was an odd result so I did some manual checking to confirm my suspicions.

As an example I clicked on a page that was supposed to have a old and obsolete path `<li><%= link_to p.title, forum_post_path(p) %></li>` that's breaks the page when I am manually clicking around I get a `no method error` as I should.

But, when I run the cucumber test and use launchy to save and open page. I don't get that error. It loads like there isn't a problem at all. The launchy page that I'm given loads the `link_to` helper with the bad `_path` like there isn't a problem at all...

The only thing I can think of is that the words that it is expecting would be there and perhaps the page is loading correctly for a brief moment before Rails spits out the method error and Cucumber is picking up on the positive result first before it returns an error.

Any possible things I can look at? I would hate to get false positives.

Edit: I just added a 1 second sleep timer (should be more than enough) and cucumber still gives me a pass.

Here are the tests so you can view it:

```
# navigation.feature
Scenario: As a user I want to be able to view a specific forum and it's posts within.
Given There is a User
Given There is a Forum
Given I am on the index
When I click the "Test forum name" link
Then I should see "Name: Test forum name"
Then I should see "Description: test description with a minimum of 20 characters.."
```

And...

```
#navigation_steps.rb
Given(/^There is a User$/) do
  User.create!(email: "user@test.com", password: "password#1")

  expect(User.first.email).to eq("user@test.com")
end

Given(/^I am on the index$/) do
  visit root_path
end

Given(/^There is a Forum$/) do
  Forum.create!(name: "Test forum name", description: "test description with a minimum of 20 characters..", user_id: User.first.id)
  expect(Forum.last.name).to eq("Test forum name")
end

When(/^I click the "([^"]*)" link$/) do |link|
  click_link link
end

Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/) do |message|
  expect(page).to have_content(message)
end
```

Screenshots:

[image: Error page]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what exactly your tests are checking for, but a couple of possible reasons for this are:

1. You're using something like `spring` to keep your test environment loaded - If you are it may not be seeing changing to routes.rb and may require restarting before it knows the routes have changed.  Solution: Restart spring or whatever your are using to keep the test env loaded
2. You incorrectly have the `web-console` gem in the test environment (it should only be in the development environment) which catches any errors and produces the nice error page.  If that error page has the text on it your test checks for (possible since it includes the surrounding code) then your test can pass - Solution: remove web-console from the test environment in your Gemfile.

Comment: Going through your ideas, I realized I made a critical error on my end.

I thought that I had posts deleted on my page doing manual deletions testing stuff, so I wasn't expecting that block of code in question to execute. I forgot that I reset my db and thus reseeded with new content that contains posts. I didn't notice until now. Thanks for taking the time to attempt to help and get me to see the problem that was in front of me.